# What is the easiest way to read different length bit fields in a byte array?

Tags: c#, logic, binaryfiles, bit

I'm trying to read a binary file (a image format) that uses different sized bit fields to refer to different colors, doing so with a dictionary for a color palette.
E.g.

> Using the following palette:

```
0   -> #FFFFFF
10  -> #FF0000  
110 -> #FF00DC  
111 -> #FF5A0C
```

> The binary data looks like this

```
0101101110101100010111
```

The problem is that when a read this file I get a `byte[]` and I don't know how to handle these variable length fields with bytes. The main issue is (using the exemple above) when reading `byte[0]` I get `01011011`, with this I'm able to convert part of the data to `#FFFFFF`, `#FF0000`, `#FF00DC` but I am left with `00000011`.

So, the question is, how could I concatenate what is left of this byte with the next one so that I could be able to read the full code.
E.g.

```
00000011 + 10101100 = 0000001110101100
```

And read this normally.

Obs: I'm using c#

**Edit:** this is a format that I'm developing for lossless image compression

Comment: There is no such thing as a *different size bit*. A bit is a bit, which on anything that C# will run on is 1/8th of a byte, and a byte is 8 bits. The image may use a *different number of bits* to refer to different colors, but that's pretty unlikely. What is the specific image format you're trying to read?

Comment: I'd probably convert 2 bytes at a time from the array to a `short` using `BitConverter.ToInt16()`. Extract the data until you are into the second byte then reload the `short` at the next byte. You'll probably have to cater for Big-Endian/Little-Endian also.

Comment: @KenWhite It's a compressed format.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm creating my own image format and I know that using different number of bits is not so common but is the best way to compress data easily, I can't just convert 2 bytes in a 16bit one because this can occur with more the 2 bites in a sequence.

Comment: @Deolus: That doesn't change the size of a bit. It may or may not be a compressed format, because the post doesn't include any information about the format, but a bit is a bit. As I said before, it may use a *different number of bits to represent different colors*, but there's still no such thing as a *different size bit*.

Comment: You could be _terribly inefficient_ and bit-shift the entire `byte[]` as you read each field, or a bit less inefficient and use a byte+bit pointer into the array, and a routine that returns the next n bits given the pointer and the `byte[]`. Consider a `class BitPosition { int bytePos; int bitPos; void MoveByBits(int numberOfBits); int ReadNBits(int numberOfBits); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample bit reader. This is not too efficient because I am returning the read bits in the lowest bit position, and then shifting to accumulate the next field.

First, a class that tracks the bit and byte position in a `byte[]` and returns the next bit.

```
public class BitPosition {
    int bytePos = 0;
    int bitPos = 0; // 0 - 7 only
    Byte[] data;

    public BitPosition(Byte[] src) => data = src;

    static byte[] byteBitMasks = new byte[] { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };
    public int ReadNextBit() {
        if (bytePos >= data.Length)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("ReadNextBit");

        int bit = (data[bytePos] & byteBitMasks[bitPos]) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        if (++bitPos > 7) {
            bitPos = 0;
            ++bytePos;
        }
        return bit;
    }
    public bool HasMoreData => bytePos < data.Length;
}
```

Now, a class to describe each entry in the compressed color palette:

```
public class ColorEntry {
    public byte marker;
    public int color;
    public int sizeInBits;
}
```

Note: If you need larger markers, you can replace `byte` with `int` or `uint`. If you need up to 64-bit markers, you will need to modify the `ColorReader` to use `uint64`.

And finally, a `ColorReader` class that reads the colors from a `byte[]` using a compressed palette and the `BitPosition` class:

```
public class ColorReader {
    BitPosition bp;

    public ColorReader(byte[] data) => bp = new BitPosition(data);

    static ColorEntry[] palette = new[] {
                new ColorEntry { marker = 0b0, color = 0xFFFFFF, sizeInBits = 1 },
                new ColorEntry { marker = 0b10, color = 0xFF0000, sizeInBits = 2 },
                new ColorEntry { marker = 0b110, color = 0xFF00DC, sizeInBits = 3 },
                new ColorEntry { marker = 0b111, color = 0xFF5A0C, sizeInBits = 3 },
            };

    public IEnumerable<ColorEntry> Colors() {
        while (bp.HasMoreData) {
            int bitsSoFar = 0;
            int numBits = 0;
            do {
                int nextBit = bp.ReadNextBit();
                ++numBits;
                bitsSoFar |= nextBit;

                var nextCE = palette.FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.sizeInBits == numBits && ce.marker == bitsSoFar);
                if (nextCE != null) {
                    yield return nextCE;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    bitsSoFar <<= 1;
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the class like so:

```
var data = new byte[] { 0b01011011, 0b10101100, 0b01011100 };
var cr = new ColorReader(data);
var ans = cr.Colors().Select(c => c.color).ToList();
```